# WP e-Commerce hook after creating order?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am looking for a hook which will be triggered after someone submit checkout form and order placed.

Comment: you can use the hook `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` after the order is created.

Comment: woocommerce? I use WP eCommerce plugin, not Woocommerce

Comment: oh sorry, I read your question too quickly.